# Spring-boot, how to curl or create rest endpoint for sentry DSN

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, sentry

I am using spring-boot-1.4.0. In my project i am using sentry for logging, sometimes log events are not reflected in sentry.While browsing google about this issue i saw something called "[Raven-Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/)" but it was written using Python. Is there any Raven-sentry available for spring-boot.I am using following [Raven-callback](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/logback/) but still I am unsure how to  curl or create a rest endpoint which would let me know the status of sentry whether it is up or down. Please let me know for any more details even i am ready to provide a code samples if needed.

Your help should be appreciable.

As per Brett comments I have updated my question by providing Python Sentry connection test link:

[Python-sentry-test](http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/track-exceptions-with-sentry-quick-setup-guide/)

In the above link they are running the test to find out connection to sentry is successful or not. Similarly i want to check the connection to sentry is successful or not via spring-boot.Also i would like to add sentry status to health check, so that when ever my logging events are not reflected in sentry, immediately i will flip the health of sentry to down.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. If you're using raven-logback then you'll need to configure it as described here: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/tree/master/raven-logback You'll need to create an account at https://sentry.io to get a DSN that you can use to configure the client.

Comment: @Brett thank you for your comment. I configured sentry and I am able to see the logs,exception etc in sentry but some times I cannot see the events in sentry, so I want to curl or create rest endpoint which would return the response of sentry status is that possible? In python it's possible, is it possible in sprint-boot ?

Comment: Can you give an example or link of what you mean in Python? I'm not sure I understand what the endpoint would be doing?

Comment: @Brett Thanks a lot for your continuous reply.I have updated my question and also provided the python sentry test link please let me know for anymore clarifications.